# Bundle map is always null while calling activity

Tags: android

I am trying to set a bundle object with extras in an intent. but it is always return null.

**Activity A :-**

```
Intent connectionIntent = new Intent(DoctorCreateEvent.this, EventsSelectConnectionsActivity.class);
connectionIntent.putExtras(getCreateEventParamBundle());
startActivityForResult(connectionIntent, 123);

private Bundle getCreateEventParamBundle() {
        Bundle paramBundle = new Bundle();
        String startDateTime = Utility.LocalToUTC(mStartDateTextView.getTag() + " " + mEventStartTimeTextView.getTag());
        String endDateTime = Utility.LocalToUTC(mEndDateTextView.getTag() + " " + mEventEndTimeTextView.getTag());
        paramBundle.putString(ServiceConstant.USER_ID, Utility.getSharedPrefStringData(mAct, PrefConstant.USER_ID));
        paramBundle.putString(ServiceConstant.EVENT_NAME, mEventNameTv.getText().toString().trim());
        paramBundle.putString(ServiceConstant.EVENT_DESCRIPTION, mEventDescTv.getText().toString().trim());
        paramBundle.putString(ServiceConstant.EVENT_START_DATE, startDateTime);
        paramBundle.putString(ServiceConstant.EVENT_END_DATE, endDateTime);
        paramBundle.putString(ServiceConstant.EVENT_START_TIME, startDateTime);
        paramBundle.putString(ServiceConstant.EVENT_END_TIME, endDateTime);
        paramBundle.putString(ServiceConstant.EVENT_ADDRESS, mEventAddressTv.getText().toString().trim());
        paramBundle.putString(ServiceConstant.EVENT_COUNTRY, mCountryId + "");
        paramBundle.putString(ServiceConstant.EVENT_STATE, mStateId + "");
        paramBundle.putString(ServiceConstant.EVENT_CITY, mCityId + "");
        paramBundle.putString(ServiceConstant.EVENT_PINCODE, mPinCodeEditText.getText().toString().trim());
        paramBundle.putString(ServiceConstant.EVENT_ISGUEST_FRIEND_ADD_PERMISSION, /*mGuestCanInviteChkBox.isChecked() ? "1" :*/ "0");
        paramBundle.putString(ServiceConstant.EVENT_IS_URGENT_APPROVAL, "0"); // Todo for the time being urgent payment is hidden as discusses with P.M
        paramBundle.putParcelableArrayList(ServiceConstant.EVENT_INVITED_FRIENDS, eventsInvitedFriendsArrayList);
        paramBundle.putString(ServiceConstant.EVENT_ID, "");
        paramBundle.putString(ServiceConstant.EVENT_IS_PUBLISH, AppConstant.EVENT_PUBLISH);
        paramBundle.putSerializable(AppConstant.KEY_CREATE_EVENT_PARAM_IMAGE, getfile());
        return paramBundle;
    }
```

**Activity B :-**

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
```

in Activity A, when I debug and evaluate, I can see my bundle and the data I am setting perfectly, but when I evaluate in Activity B, the map is null in the bundle object.

Comment: Check for the parcelable data. comment or remove other data which you are sending and check only for parcelable data

Comment: Not working. I thought maybe i am sending too much data so i tried only sending one data. Actually the point is, this code is working for the previous activity i am starting, but not for this. Strange issue

Comment: Check with any string data. If that also not working then obviously the issue is different.

Comment: did u recieved the data on **onActivityResult() **